# Combining audio and video in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How do you combine a custom audio in a video using Xamarin.Forms or in Xamarin.IOS? I don't have any clues how to do this in Xamarin.iOS

The custom audio will be coming from a video stream which I need to parse. This is another problem actually and the parsed audio will then be combined into a video recording from iOS.

The result would be like the musical.ly application.

Comment: refer to https://developer.telerik.com/featured/merging-audio-video-native-ios/